# is determinant of A times A transposed bigger than or equal to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

We have an m by n matrix A of real numbers where n is bigger than m.
Prove that determinant of A times A transposed is bigger than or equal 0.

Comment: $\det A=\det A^T$ and $\det(AB)=\det A\det B$

Comment: @Alessandro that only works then both matrixes are square. Here, $A$ does not have a determinant.

Comment: @ZachStone woops I should spend more time reading the questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go a rather different route than the other answer here, you can use Cauchy-Binet to write $\det AA^T$ as a sum of squares. Cauchy-Binet tells us that
$$
\det AA^T = \sum_{s\in S} \det A_{m,s} \det A^T_{s,m} = \sum_{s\in S} (\det A_{m,s})^2
$$

Where $S$ is the set of all size $m$ subsets of $[n]$, and $A_{m,s}$ is the submatrix from selecting only those $m$ rows from $A$ specified by $s$.

Of course to use this, you'd have to have proved Cauchy-Binet, which isn't too hard.

Answer (score 3):

Since $AA'$ is positive semidefinite, in the eigendecomposition (or Jordan Canonical form) of $AA' = S^{-1}JS$, the diagonal matrix $J$ only has positive values on the diagonal, hence
$$\det(AA') = \det(S^{-1}JS) = \det(S^{-1})\det(J)\det(S)=\det(J) \geq 0$$

Comment: To see that $A A^t$ is positive semidefinite, that is, $x \cdot A A^t x \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ (where $\cdot$ is the usual dot product on $\mathbb{R}^m$), we have
$$
x \cdot A A^t x = x^t A A^t x = (A^t x)^t (A^t x) = \|A^t x \|^2 \geq 0 
$$

Comment: Why the eigendecomposition of AA′ exists?

Comment: @SayedMahdi It always exists.

Comment: @NigelOvermars could you give me a proof?

Comment: @SayedMahdi https://www.math.vt.edu/people/renardym/class_home/Jordan.pdf I will edit my answer to also include this name of the theorem.

Comment: @NigelOvermars could you diagonalize this:\begin{matrix}
 2 & 1  \\
 0 &  2  
\end{matrix} ?

Comment: Jordan from is not the same as diagonal. That matrix you wrote is already in Jordan form. All matrixes have a Jordan form.